# I am working on search and get a index not found error?

Tags: django

I get a regular "index not found" in django, my code is as follow, I am trying to implement search.  The string passed to ReceiveStr(String) will look for a file name, in this case "views.py" based on a search for '.' and ' ' (space)

```
    def ReceiveStr(String):


        n = len(String)
        print(n)
        d = String.find('.')

        g =[]
        t=' '
        res1 = []
        res2 = []
        res = [i for i in range(len(String)) if String.startswith(t, i)] 

        m = len(res)
        for x in String:


            for i in range(0,len(res)-1):

                 if res[i] < d:
                 print(res[i])
                 print (d)
                 res1[i] = res[i]
                 print (res1)
                 break




    ReceiveStr('Where can I find views.py ')
```

Error at res1[i] = res[i]
I have tried everything.  The other thing I can't assign a string object to a list[i] ?  What is the work around ?

Comment: `res1` is an empty list, you cannot assign/access members of an empty list by index. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: there are too many arrays and comparisons going on in your code :) I really could'nt follow. can you explain what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line

```
res1[i] = res[i]
```

to

```
res1 = [res[i]]
```

as you cannot reference the first index of a list without actually having any item in it.

Comment: I did work around finally and I see what you suggested works too:

I used this code :
           -->  e.append(ls1[j])